# What does "a whole mood" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does "a whole mood" mean? I know the means of *whole* as well as *mood*, but I don't know when they are connected. I also looked both of them in the dictionaries and can't find this usage. It's from a comment under this YouTube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HtTUsOKjWyQ

> Lmao the dude who looked up then sat back down is a whole mood. He's like 
> "The hell-?  Oh Ok"

Comment: That whole piece of speech is severely non-standard street-talk. A whole mood is probably an angry mood.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Within the past couple of years, a new slang meaning of the word “mood” has emerged. It’s used to say something is **relatable**. “A whole mood” is used to describe something that’s especially relatable (though it’s maybe not as strong as the things that are “mood [AF](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/af)”).

See also:

- [What does it mean when you say something "is a mood"?](https://www.quora.com/What-does-it-mean-when-you-say-something-is-a-mood)
- [What does "thats a mood" mean? I said "Im addicted to youtube" and she said "thats a mood"](https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/13725651)
- [Everyone on Twitter is in a ‘big mood’—here’s what that means](https://www.dailydot.com/unclick/what-is-big-mood/)
- [Know Your Meme: Big Mood](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/big-mood)

It is **not** the same as being “in a mood” or “moody”, which are negative. In fact, “mood” in the new slang sense can be used in response to positive or neutral things, where it would make no sense to be upset, such as [this picture of a “smirking cheerleader”](https://knowyourmeme.com/photos/1335489-big-mood).

Comment: Gosh, you learn something every day… I guess anyone considering _using_ this term should be aware that it's likely to confuse a lot of people!

Comment: @gidds I don't think this is noticeably different from any other new slang. The youth aren't going to hold back from using it because oldsters don't know what it means. That's part of the fun of it, even.

Answer (score 6):

"Is a mood" (*not* "is in a mood", which is a more standard and older, more widespread expression) is modern American slang.

As an almost middle-aged British English speaker, this variety of slang isn't part of my native vocabulary and I can only try and work it out by the context.

The way I interpret "...is a mood" or "...is a whole mood" is that the particular person or action is engaging in an action or mode of behaviour that epitomises a particular mood and deserves to be classed as a whole mood of its own rather than subsumed within an existing mood-describing adjective such as "sad", "grumpy", "angry", etc.

TheMarySue recently had an [article](https://www.themarysue.com/sebastian-stan-yelling-about-people-still-going-outside-is-a-mood/) titled "Sebastian Stan Yelling About People Still Going Outside Is a Mood".

There was recently a similar question about what "...is a mood" means on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-does-it-mean-when-you-say-something-is-a-mood).  One answer was "When something/someone does something so relatable that it is an entire mood".  Another was that "If you say 'something is a mood' you attribute an atmosphere or an emotion to something physical".

Comment: It's hilarious how many of those Quora answers are cluelessly wrong...

Comment: @LawnmowerMan That's Quora for you.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.cyberdefinitions.com/definitions/MOOD.html, mood is still used on social media with its original meaning, as well as with a slightly newer definition.

> The word mood actually means "a temporary state of mind or feeling."
> In this context, mood is often used on social media with a hashtag
> (#mood) and an accompanying image, to indicate how the poster is
> feeling at that moment.
>
> However, mood is also used to express agreement with
> a sentiment (positive or negative) that someone has shared. In this
> context, mood means something like "I can relate to that feeling," or
> "I agree."

None of these definitions really fit this use of whole mood, but the first one probably comes closest. The mood of the guy in question seems to go from inquisitive to uninterested in an instant.